# getting error :Type '[null, Dispatch<SetStateAction<null>>]' is not assignable to type in typescript react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i am working on typescript project,i want to `useState` for `setInterval` function, but i am getting below error, i am using statement for `useState` like this, can anyone please help me how to resolve this issue? any help will be really appreciated.

```
const [intervalData, setIntervalData] : [null | NodeJS.Timeout, (interval: null | NodeJS.Timeout) => void] = useState(null);
```

Error :

```
Type '[null, Dispatch<SetStateAction<null>>]' is not assignable to type '[Timeout | null, (interval: Timeout | null) => void]'.
  Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<null>>' is not assignable to type '(interval: Timeout | null) => void'.
    Types of parameters 'value' and 'interval' are incompatible.
      Type 'Timeout | null' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<null>'.
        Type 'Timeout' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<null>'.
          Type 'Timeout' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: null): null'.ts(2322)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't specify a type parameter to `useState` the type of the state will be inferred from the value passed to `useState`. Since you pass in `null`, the type of the state will be `null`, meaning that it can have no other value except `null`.

You can specify a wider type for the state as a type parameter:

```
const [intervalData, setIntervalData]:[null | NodeJS.Timeout, (interval: null | NodeJS.Timeout) => void] = useState<null | NodeJS.Timeout>(null);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwK4GcCmBlGBDGa4C+cAZlBCHAORRrYDGMlAUEwHbYhopj34ByEACZoAUhkRM4UuGgAekWHDoAbbChRwAKqDQQk8BHDBRgAN1z5ZAQgBcrJMuWEmBJnQisU8ANrBWeKHNlABFcbAAaOHQYAEl-NEDsELCAXRtve0c4AB84AWExADptTj0YSIAKPwCgmzhMp1z80QxinTKASjgAXgA+OFMIYEEUnrhUTBw8AB4GnLyhFrbS-V6Kho6AbiA)

Note: I would drop the type annotation from the `const` altogether, but I'm guessing that might have been added just for the example in the question.

Comment: thanks, that is working but when i used return clearInterval(intervalData); i am getting this error  No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(intervalId: Timeout): void', gave the following error.

Comment: The problem there might be that you have both definitions from node and from DOM libraries of `setInterval` and `clearInterval`